# Get shorter response from Google Geocode Api

Tags: json, google-maps, google-geocoding-api

This is my Get request for api:

```
http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?latlng=50.126886,14.421954&language=cs&sensor=false
```

And I get really long response which is not ideal for mobile device. So which parameters should I add to get just result with first `"address_components"` and `"formatted_address"` but don't get other things (they are useless for me). Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you can limit the response (https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/).

What you *can* do (if you really want to limit the response) is to proxy the response through your own server and remove some of the results.

Are you sure, that your problem is the size of the result? More than often, most of the time spent on downloading a website is spent initializing requests. Which basically means you should favor fewer requests over size per request.

Good resources:

- [HTTP Requests vs File Size?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9855545/http-requests-vs-file-size)
- http://developer.yahoo.com/blogs/ydn/high-performance-sites-rule-1-fewer-http-requests-7163.html
- [Should I aim for fewer HTTP requests or more cacheable CSS files?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2685520/should-i-aim-for-fewer-http-requests-or-more-cacheable-css-files)

Comment: I think you're right. Thanks for answer and links to that articles.